# Opening Port for Windows Azure Service Bus

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I am using Service Bus with the following code

```
      TransportClientEndpointBehavior relayCredentials = new TransportClientEndpointBehavior();
        relayCredentials.TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedSecretTokenProvider(issuerName, issuerSecret);

        Uri address = ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri("sb", serviceNamespace, "MyService");

        Console.Write("....");
```

I am wondering if is it possible to specify port that shall be used by Service bus, instead of it taking random port and using it. Binding is netTcpRelayBinding

Answer (score 1):

The port will not be assigned in random passion. For netTcpRelayBinding it will use 9352 for HTTP (9352/9353 if using Hybrid).

You can see the port requirements for ServiceBus from this [msdn site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee732535.aspx).